# How can I show a message in Django url?

Tags: django, return, httpresponse, jsonresponse

My views.py works properly under the path in urlpattern I have defined.

I have a for loop and I want to show a message in the browser screen I've tried with httpResponse and JsonResponse, but I cant or get some errors.

My views.py function is:

```
def all_disconnect (request):
    try:
        url_cnc = 'http://**********************'
        auth = {'username':'*****', 'password':'*******'}
        log = requests.post(url_cnc, data=auth)
        log.cookies['SESSION']  
        cookie_log = log.cookies['SESSION']
        peticion = requests.Session()
        peticion.headers.update({'Cookie' : 'SESSION='+cookie_log})
        #--------------DOWN IS THE PROBLEM-----------------------------------
        for meter in all_meter:
            x = peticion.post('http://150.214.144.246:8443/ws/v1/cg/dc/meters/'+ meter +'/control/plc/Disconnect/immediate')
            HttpResponse ('El meter '+meter+' ha sido desconectado')
        return JsonResponse("fin", safe=False)
    except ValueError as e:
        return JsonResponse(e.args[0])
```

I can print `"fin"`, but if I put JsonResponse inside the loop to print each "meter" I get some error.

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: `HttpResponse` is a class that represents the response of a HTTP request, since you do not return it, that is basically a *no op*. It is however not very clear to me what you mean with *message* here. If you want to render a message, then typically one uses an AJAX call and let JS render the content.

Comment: It's not a message at all, I want to show in the screen the sentence with different values of "meter" in the loop...Is it possible or is can only be implementing a view for that url-path??

Comment: What error are you getting when you return `JsonResponse` inside the loop?  And by 'message' are you referring to the URL or some on-screen content you want to display?

Comment: First iteration is correct but second it put: '  Not Found: /favicon.ico
[11/May/2019 21:03:22] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2438  ' and by message I'm refering on-screen content at the same way a python print do

Comment: The error I put was using google chrome, if I use postman don´t have this error, but it don't print that I want and in the first iteration it get out from the loop, so only do the first iteration in the program